# Explode array [(str), (int)] in column dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, explode

I have a dataframe:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({
       'day': ['11', '12'],
       'City': ['[(Mumbai, 1),(Bangalore, 2)]', '[(Pune, 3),(Mumbai, 4),(Delh, 5)]']
    })

   day                               City
0  11       [(Mumbai, 1),(Bangalore, 2)]
1  12  [(Pune, 3),(Mumbai, 4),(Delh, 5)]
```

I want to make an explode. But when I do that, nothing changes.

```
df2 = df.explode('City')
```

What I want to get at the output

```
  day            City
0  11     (Mumbai, 1)
1  11  (Bangalore, 2)
2  12       (Pune, 3)
3  12     (Mumbai, 4)
4  12       (Delh, 5)
```

Comment: You have strings, you need lists to explode. What is the wanted output? a string or tuple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `explode` strings. You need to find a way to convert to lists.

Assuming you have city names with only letters (or spaces) you could use a regex to add the quotes and convert to list with `ast.literal_eval`:

```
from ast import literal_eval

df['City'] = (df['City']
              .str.replace(r'([a-zA-Z ]+),', r'"\1",', regex=True)
              .apply(literal_eval)
              )

df2 = df.explode('City', ignore_index=True)
```

output:

```
  day            City
0  11     (Mumbai, 1)
1  11  (Bangalore, 2)
2  12       (Pune, 3)
3  12     (Mumbai, 4)
4  12       (Delh, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'day': ['11', '12'],
    'City': ['[(Mumbai, 1),(Bangalore, 2)]', '[(Pune, 3),(Mumbai, 4),(Delh, 5)]']
})


df['City'] = [re.sub("\),\(",")-(", x) for x in df['City']]
df['City'] = [re.sub("\[|\]|\(|\)","", x) for x in df['City']]
df['City'] = [x.split("-") for x in df['City']]
df['City']
df2 = df.explode('City').reset_index(drop=True)
```

you have to process the string and convert it to list before explode

```
  day          City
0  11     Mumbai, 1
1  11  Bangalore, 2
2  12       Pune, 3
3  12     Mumbai, 4
4  12       Delh, 5
```